# Aligning bullets in JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, indentation, dynamic-reports

The following post answers that bullets can have a hanging indent / be aligned by adding left-padding.

[Jasper Report HTML bullet hanging indent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025092/jasper-report-html-bullet-hanging-indent)

However, when I tried to do that, the whole line would move and so the bullets would no longer be padded

So the text:

```
- TEXT TEXT TEXT
TEXT TEXT TEXT
```

would become:

```
    - TEXT TEXT TEXT
    TEXT TEXT TEXT
```

when what I want is:

```
- TEXT TEXT TEXT
  TEXT TEXT TEXT
```

How can I line up the second line of the bullets. Is there a hanging indent/first line indent that accepts negative numbers, or any other method that I could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around a bit I found that what I could do was add padding to the whole paragraph and make the first line a negative indent.

I am using an api called dynamic reports so the way I did it was

```
TextColumnBuilder<String> itemBulletsCol = col.column(
    "", COLUMN_NAME_BULLET_LIST, type.stringType()
).setStyle(....
        .setFirstLineIndent(-10)
        .setPadding(10)
);
```